# Estimating the parameters of a stochastic asset price models using Matlab

Tags: time-series, estimation, matlab, stochastic-processes

I am simulating asset prices using different existing stochastic models as well as my own proposed stochastic models. I would like to estimate the parameters of each model by using the historical spot prices. I believe this can be done via different methods of MLE,MCMC etc..

However as I do not know the density function of my models (some can be very complex), I was wondering whether it is correct and/or possible To:

1. Using the Matlab ksdensity function  obtain the empirical pdf of the asset prices up to 'T' days
2. Minimize the difference between this empirical pdf and the ksdensity of simulated prices ('N' paths and up the to the same 'T' days) to obtain the model parameters.

If this is a correct way of thinking I would also appreciate any hints on how I would go about coding this objective function.